# no details are getting displayed in the error

Tags: python, python-turtle

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title("ping pong")
wn.bgcolor("black")
wn.setup(width=800, height= 600)
wn.tracer(0)
wn.exitonclick()

#Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape("square")
paddle_a.color("white")
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0)

#Paddle B
paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_b.speed(0)
paddle_b.shape("square")
paddle_b.color("white")
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.goto(350, 0)

#Main game loop
while True:
    wn.update()
```

why is it displaying an error in paddle a?  also the error does not contain any details. I use visual studio 2019. instead of displaying a
turtle screen with both the paddles it just displays a blank turtle screen.

Comment: What error output does appear?

Comment: with this part of my code, it should display a turtle screen with paddle A on the left side and paddle B on the right side

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your program is over by line seven:

```
wn.exitonclick()
```

Nothing after that statement gets executed.  This statement turns control over to tkinter's event loop and doesn't return until turtle is shut down.  Comment it out to see the difference.

Generally `exitonclick()`, `mainloop()`, `done()`, etc. should be the last thing a program does after setting up it's interface and event handlers.

And your final `while True:` has no business in an event-driven world like turtle.

Comment: thanks a lot, you have really got me out of the box

Comment: @VedPawar, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)